# Line break after every 4 consecutive numbers in string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"user modified avdd on december 1989user created avdd on august 21th, 2010"
```

I would like to append a new line after every four digits, so the end result will be:

```
"user modified avdd on december 1989
 user created avdd on august 21th, 2010"
```

I already know that `\/d/d/d/d\` will match those numbers in regex.

I tried doing it this way:

```
 var rows = "user modified avdd on december 1989user created avdd on august 21th, 2010";
 var logs = row.replace(\/d/d/d/d\,"\n");
```

(and then looping the `.replace`) but the result omits the 4 digits from the result.

Can i replace without ommiting ? is there a better approach ?

**EDIT:** as suggested i tried `.replace(/\d{4}/, "\n")` problem is this output **removes the numbers from the final string**:

so im getting

```
"user modified avdd on december
 user created avdd on august 21th, 2010"
```

instead of the desired output:

```
"user modified avdd on december 1989
 user created avdd on august 21th, 2010"
```

Comment: you need `\d` not `/d` - you have your \ and / confused - i.e `/\d\d\d\d/` ... or better `/\d{4}/` - you'll also need the global (g) modifier to do "all" of them

Comment: @JaromandaX you are correct, but as stated even with `.replace(/\d{4}/, "\n")` the numbers are removed from the final string, not sure how to solve that one

Answer (score 2):

U need to use the feature called "Capturing Group".

Parenthesis around a section of a regex allows you to capture it and append it in the replaced string with $1, $2, etc.

This function does the trick :

```
var logs = rows.replace(/(\d{4})/g,'$1\n');
```

(\d{4}) = captures an occurence of 4 digits;
/g = global parameter to replace all occurences ( so no need to loop after the execution )

By the way, on a robustness point of view, you need to be SURE that a user cant have 4 successive digits in his id !